# Cannot declare class 'TestCommandRun', because the name is already in use

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using `laravel 5.4`.

I am using `php artisan list`, but get the following error:

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Coding Projects\demo_laravel>php artisan list
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class TestCommandRun, because the name is already in use in C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Coding Projects\demo_laravel\app\Console\Commands\TestCommandRun.php on line 109
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Coding Projects\demo_laravel\artisan:0
PHP   2. App\Console\Kernel->handle() C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Coding Projects\demo_laravel\artisan:37
PHP   3. App\Console\Kernel->getArtisan() C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Coding Projects\demo_laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php:121
PHP   4. Illuminate\Console\Application->resolveCommands() C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Coding Projects\demo_laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php:317
PHP   5. Illuminate\Console\Application->resolve() C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Coding Projects\demo_laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Application.php:242
PHP   6. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make() C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Coding Projects\demo_laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Application.php:228
PHP   7. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make() C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Coding Projects\demo_laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:732
PHP   8. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve() C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Coding Projects\demo_laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:586
PHP   9. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->build() C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Coding Projects\demo_laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:631
PHP  10. ReflectionClass->__construct() C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Coding Projects\demo_laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:752
PHP  11. spl_autoload_call() C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Coding Projects\demo_laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:752
PHP  12. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Coding Projects\demo_laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:752
PHP  13. Composer\Autoload\includeFile() C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Coding Projects\demo_laravel\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php:322

In TestCommandRun.php line 109:

  Cannot declare class TestCommandRun, because the name is already in use
```

My Command has the right name:

```
class TestCommandRun extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'TestCommandRun:run';
```

Within my Kernel.php I have added it to `$commands` section:

```
protected $commands = [
    '\App\Console\Commands\TestCommandRun',        
];
```

Any suggestions why I get the above error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have two commands with the same class name `TestCommandRun`. So, you need to delete one.

Also it's a good idea to run `composer du` command after that.

Comment: Thx for your reply! What does `composer du` do exactly?